# How to select result with empty set

Tags: sql

I have sql query:

```
select * from table where id in (1,2)
```

1,2 are parameters which I add there dynamically. But what If I have empty set:

```
select * from table where id in ()
```

then this query call exception:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00936: missing expression
```

how should I create sql with empty set

Comment: You should avoid empty sets, after all if the set is empty, the query result is empty. Check outside, if set is not empty then select, if empty, then skip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always add `null` to your set, so when the real set is empty, you get no syntax error:

```
select * from table where id in (null,1,2)
```

vs

```
select * from table where id in (null)
```

Your generator would be simpler, too, because you can print a `,` in front of every item that you add, without checking if it's the first one or not.

Of course since you are generating your SQL, the standard precautions against [SQL Injection](http://xkcd.com/327/) apply: do not let user input anywhere near the SQL that you generate.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 select * from table where id in (null)
```